# cmd doesn't output results to a file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, jsonlint

I'm trying to use the cmd line, eventually putting it into a .bat to run a program, taking the return value and putting it into a .txt file.  In this script it runs the program, creates the .txt file, but the .txt file is blank, while the program puts out a bunch of text on one line:

This is the command:

```
jsonlint test.json -c -q > test1.txt
```

The test1.txt gets create, but is blank.  The program returns this value:

> test.json: line 3, col13, found: 'NUMBER' - expected: 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']'.**

Why would this return value not be getting saved to the test1.txt file?  Any thoughts or ideas are most appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: That's not *results*, it's an *error*. Thus, it's probably on stderr, not stdout.

Answer (score 0):

As Charles has mentioned, your output is actually an error indicating that your JSON file `test.json` is syntactically incorrect on line 3 col 13.

If you want to have whatever is output regardless of it being `STDOUT` or `STDERR`, then at the end of your command you can add `2>&1` to redirect your `STDERR` to `STDOUT`, so it would look like this:

```
jsonlint test.json -c -q > test1.txt 2>&1
```

More on redirecting error messages [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout).

Comment: I have down-voted this as it is simply a regurgitation if somebody else's comments. In addition to that, the comments clearly showed that this question has already been answered on this site, so is a duplicate, which didn't need answering again.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't know it wouldn't just put out everything on the line.  Good information.  Sorry it's a duplicate, but I searched this site and didn't find anything to help, so obviously it's not coming up with the query I put in.  Perhaps my verbiage may be of help to someone else in the future.  Thanks again.